# Add ToolTip to every ColumnHeader DataGrid Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagrid

I'm new in Silverlight 5, Visual Studio 2012, C#, Blend...

I'm using this example to add tooltip to my DataGrid:

```
var style = new Style(typeof(System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DataGridColumnHeader)); style.Setters.Add(new Setter(ToolTipService.ToolTipProperty, "Este es mi ToolTip"));

myDataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle = style;
```

But this ToolTip is put in everyone cols, How I do a different TolTip for every col??

Thank, regards from México

Comment: why cant you put in your xaml code? you want to do dynamically?

Comment: no really...see below

Answer (score 0):

Don't put the tooltip in the style, put it in the xaml of each column header.

```
<ColumnHeader>
<ToolTipService.ToolTip>

   <ToolTip Content="Turtle"></ToolTip>

</ToolTipService.ToolTip>
</ColumnHeader>
```

[More on Tooltips](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Using-the-ToolTip-control-in-Silverlight-2.aspx)

Comment: I'm use a ResourceDictionary with a personalize disgn for all my controls, I'm using a ResourceDictionary with a custom design for all my controls:

Comment: in xaml:  `<sdk:DataGrid ....                      Style="{StaticResource DataGridMtto}" ...                    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>`
                        `<Style TargetType="dataprimitives:DataGridColumnHeader">
                            <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ToolTip" Value="Fecha de la OC" />
                        </Style>
                    </sdk:DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>` ... The ToolTip is ok, but the ColumnHeaderStyle is missing...

Comment: See sample that I added to answer.

Comment: Thank you very much @GregHollywood, but when I put <ColumnHeader> say me "No se encontró el tipo 'ColumnHeader'. Compruebe que no falta una referencia a un ensamblado" I'm trying other ways based on what you tell me

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't know Spanish.

Comment: Hi @GregHollywood, this to mean the Type 'ColumnHeader' not exists, Check for missing a reference to an assembly

Comment: btw I'm using silverlight 5

Comment: I am sorry, I don't have any more suggestions on this.

Answer (score 0):

Put this style in one of the resource dictionaries that will be in scope (for example, the application wide one):

```
        <Style TargetType="sdk:DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ToolTip" Value="Este es mi ToolTip" />
        </Style>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, @John, but I don't understand you very well, then I need include this for every column in the Dictionary? and how I use this in the aplication's xaml? Thks a lot

Comment: I'm trying anyway, thks

Comment: Ok, @John, I added it in my dictionary, and shows me "Este es mi ToolTip" at every column of the DataGrid, now, to customize this in my application, how I do it?